# How do I properly respond to "Have you sorted everything out"?

Tags: meaning, slang

There is a guy at my university from another class asking me "Have you sorted everything out"every day, I don't know how to properly respond to that which is embarrassing. What is the best reply to that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about how the English language is used.  You are looking for social or psychological advice.

Comment: Why would he ask that every day? Is there an ongoing issue that needs to be resolved?

Comment: @Tuffy I am asking how to reply for that question any not any psychological advice lol! Even though I described the situation!

Comment: @RichouHunter Hos first language is not English so I think he don’t even know how to use it!

Comment: @AussieKenDoll What is there about the language (vocabulary or grammar) of the question that makes it difficult to answer appropriately?

Comment: @Tuffy it is about English language usage!

Comment: I might be tempted to come up with a playful retort such as "Yep, all done and dusted"... (whether or not that happens to be true)…

Comment: People are trying to find out what the 'everything' is that you are supposed to be sorting out! Is it just his clumsy way of asking if you are OK?

Comment: I would say "Yes.  As a matter of fact I'm out of sorts."  Leaving the guy baffled, no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

> Have you sorted everything out?

This is a perfectly good sentence with a subject pronoun, a verb and an object.

So why has the OP got a problem?

It has to be about the reference of the noun *everything*.

It is not exactly a problem of grammar, though that could be argued.  It is more about propositional reference.  The noun ‘everything’, like pronouns, is context dependent.  We know and understand exactly what the sentence means.  But we (I mean those of us who are not parties to the discussion) have no idea what the speaker is talking about.

A question like this presupposes that there is some list of things to be sorted by the addressee.  For example, perhaps they are planning a party, or organising a trip to Europe, and the addressee is supposed to be getting it all ‘sorted’.

Since you ask the question, we have to assume that there is no such context.  So the sentence is malformed, but void of reference and therefore meaning.  It has no truth value.  You know of no conditions under which an answer of *yes* or *no* would be true or false.

Well, there is a second possibility:  that the speaker has a personal catchphrase, which is his way of asking how you are getting on in general.  It has been suggested that you answer: “yes, fine, thank you, and have you?”. If he gets angry or looks at you as if you are crazy, you can exclude that possibility.  If he says “great”, you have your answer.

Or you could say:  “Not yet, I’ve been busy”. and see how he reacts.

Or you could say:  “What do you mean?”. and see whether and hoe he reacts.

But none of these is about the use of the English language.  They are strategies for dealing with an inexplicable sequence of utterances.  So they are performative rather than communicative.  None of your ‘answers’ is intended as an answer.  It is more like a litmus test.  So it is about what you **do** about what seems to be strange **behaviour**.

By the way, these examples of possible responses are only used to illustrate why the issue is not one of language.  I am not recommending that any of them should be attempted.  Far from it.